# Prestashop 1.7: Getting the Shop Group ID from the context?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

`\Context::getContext()->shop->id` allows us to get the Shop ID from the context.

I've looking for `\Context::getContext()->shop->group_id` or `\Context::getContext()->group_shop->id` in the class and in Google, but didn't find anything pertinent.

How can I get the Shop Group ID from the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Context::getContext()->shop->getContextShopGroupID();`